# Error compiling guvcview against newest FFmpeg

Tags: 16.04, compiling, ffmpeg, sed, guvcview

Under Xenial Xerus I am compiling the release version of guvcview against the latest git FFmpeg. In the latest FFmpeg `PIX_FMT_YUV420P` has been replaced with `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P` and I suspect this variable must be replaced through the guvcview source.

The error that breaks the compile is this:

```
jpeg_decoder.c:1439:33: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PIX_FMT_YUV422P'; did you mean
      'AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P'?
        codec_data->context->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV422P;
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                       AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P
```

Does anybody have a patch or even some `sed` magic to fix this issue?

**References:**

- [#34 [SOLVED] guvcview 2.0.4 compilation failure: 'PIX_FMT_YUV420P' undeclared](https://sourceforge.net/p/guvcview/tickets/34/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`guvcview-ffmpeg3.patch`](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk/guvcview-ffmpeg3.patch?h=packages/guvcview) from Arch Linux:

```
--- a/gview_v4l2core/jpeg_decoder.c
+++ b/gview_v4l2core/jpeg_decoder.c
@@ -1436,7 +1436,7 @@
        exit(-1);
    }

-   codec_data->context->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV422P;
+   codec_data->context->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P;
    codec_data->context->width = width;
    codec_data->context->height = height;
    //jpeg_ctx->context->dsp_mask = (FF_MM_MMX | FF_MM_MMXEXT | FF_MM_SSE);
--- a/gview_v4l2core/uvc_h264.c
+++ b/gview_v4l2core/uvc_h264.c
@@ -970,7 +970,7 @@
    }

    h264_ctx->context->flags2 |= CODEC_FLAG2_FAST;
-   h264_ctx->context->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
+   h264_ctx->context->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    h264_ctx->context->width = width;
    h264_ctx->context->height = height;
    //h264_ctx->context->dsp_mask = (FF_MM_MMX | FF_MM_MMXEXT | FF_MM_SSE);
```

Comment: @andrew.46 Glad to help. I find the Arch repo is a good place to scrounge from.